# SPD Workflow. Skip step if item already exists

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow which, when a document is uploaded into a library called "Drop box", an Item is created in another list (called Jobs Directory) using the field "Job Name" which is specified on the initial upload of the document. This works fine. 
However, there may be more than one document uploaded for each job. We only want one list entry per job, so the idea is that the workflow only creates a list item on the first upload, then ignores this step if an item with the same Job name already exists. 
Is there a way to manage this in Sharepoint Designer 2010? 
FYI, the Job Name field in the Jobs Directory list requires unique values so currently the workflow fails at this stage and does not continue...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article might be of help for you: 
http://markeev.com/Articles/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow.aspx

Try to set a (hidden) column "previous Job Name" and set it as in the given link.

Then try running in parallels:

Step 1: If current_item:Job Name != previous Job Name: do this

Step 2: If current_item:Job Name == previous Job Name: skip

I hope this is somewhat clear for I have little Time at the moment.

Best regards,
Dom